# Python string of bytes(?) to bytes

Tags: python

Reposting this question. I am not asking about the 'b' in a string literal or how to get rid of it.

I have a string like this:

```
"b'gAAAAABgAG4-D7Wda8gIQ6mLJNQegbfgKtnQ9nxcwJzokWGsiZMNYN2igbuUVcwMHxqZNQ-Yvd8tkTo-vWGEuOK7jgfKlGSq5A=='"
```

This is originally a byte value returned by the python cryptography.fernet `encrypt()` function.

I need to pass this value to the `decrypt()` function that takes in a byte value. How do I convert this string back to a type of byte?

I have read all the similar decoding posts on string to base64 on stackoverflow but they don't address my question specifically.

I have tried various methods like `string.encode("ascii")` and `bytes(string, 'utf-8')` but I just end up with something like this:

```
b"b'gAAAAABgAG3XMnAaKN3H2y1bC-j08i8ONFwzG0SKeRyiM9dnfEo4ojegCxrY3DQB0Hf9kyM3fUId8ZZk_eQkX3GwAdboIMtk2A=='"
```

I have also tried the following

```
import base64    
byt = base64.decodebytes("b'gAAAAABgAG4-D7Wda8gIQ6mLJNQegbfgKtnQ9nxcwJzokWGsiZMNYN2igbuUVcwMHxqZNQ-Yvd8tkTo-vWGEuOK7jgfKlGSq5A=='")
```

But I ended up with an error "TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not str".

I have this problem because I want to encrypt a column of data in pandas, then write it to an Excel file along with other unencrypted columns. When I read it back later, the encrypted column ends up as a string and I get the error "TypeError: token must be bytes" when I decrypt the values.

Comment: You can use eval(): `bytes_data = eval(byte_string)`

Comment: @בנימיןכהן Never recommend `eval`, as it can run any arbitrary code.

Comment: How did you end up with the string representation of a bytes object, rather than the bytes themselves? You should fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "b'gAAAAABgAG4-D7Wda8gIQ6mLJNQegbfgKtnQ9nxcwJzokWGsiZMNYN2igbuUVcwMHxqZNQ-Yvd8tkTo-vWGEuOK7jgfKlGSq5A=='"

> This is originally a byte value returned by the python cryptography.fernet encrypt() function.

No, that's a representation of the `repr()` of a bytestring returned by fernet `encrypt()`. It will be doubly tough to decode that (though `ast.literal_eval()` would do it).

You'll need to change that encryption code to decode the bytestring back into a regular text string; since the Fernet token is ASCII safe, you can simply do that with `.decode()`.

Then, when trying to decrypt the value, you would similarly `.encode('ascii')` the text string for Fernet to consume.

Comment: Thank you so much. I managed to use `ast.literal_eval()` to convert `"b'gAAAAABgAG4-D7Wda8gIQ6mLJNQegbfgKtnQ9nxcwJzokWGsiZMNYN2igbuUVcwMHxqZNQ-Yvd8tkTo-vWGEuOK7jgfKlGSq5A=='"` back into a regular text string and using that I was able to decrypt the value.

If you have any advice about how to properly save and load a pandas dataframe with an encrypted column of values, along with other unencrypted columns of values, to an Excel file and back, I'd love to hear. I simply did a `to_excel()` because it seems most logical to me but not sure if it is good practice.